# Multiple JPanel not being printed in front of background

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I wanted to create a Calendar that creates itself dinamically depending on the month it is based of. At first, I created a background that will be used on any months, and its dimensions are 700x500 (700/7 for each day and 500/5 since every month but 28-days-February-starting-in-Monday has 5 rows of weeks). I did this with this sentences:

```
public class Graph {

    private final int sizeX = 700;
    private final int sizeY = 500;
    private Calendar calendar;


    public Graph(Calendar calendar) {
        this.calendar = calendar;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        graph(frame);
    }

    public void graph(JFrame frame) {
        buildBackground(frame);
    }

    private void buildBackground(JFrame frame) {
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(sizeX, sizeY);
        JPanel panel = new Background(sizeX, sizeY);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.validate();
        frame.repaint();
    }
}

public class Background extends JPanel {

    private int sizeX;
    private int sizeY;

    public Background(int sizeX, int sizeY) {
        this.sizeX = sizeX;
        this.sizeY = sizeY;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, sizeX, sizeY);
    }
}
```

And that works correctly, a dark gray background is created correctly. The problem appears when I try to create small rectangles that represents the days; I designed a class which I want to represent those rectangles on a certain coordinates:

```
public class DayRectangle extends JPanel {

    private int posX;
    private int posY;
    private int day;

    public DayRectangle(int posX, int posY, int day) {
        this.posX = posX;
        this.posY = posY;
        this.day = day;
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.fillRect(posX, posY, 60, 60);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension (60, 60);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("(%d,%d):%d", posX, posY, day);
    }
}
```

Rectangles' coordinates are created correctly, since this are the content of the `ArrayList` of `DayRectangle`:

```
[(20,20):1, (120,20):2, (220,20):3, (320,20):4, (420,20):5, (520,20):6, (620,20):7, (20,120):8, (120,120):9, (220,120):10, (320,120):11, (420,120):12, (520,120):13, (620,120):14, (20,220):15, (120,220):16, (220,220):17, (320,220):18, (420,220):19, (520,220):20, (620,220):21, (20,320):22, (120,320):23, (220,320):24, (320,320):25, (420,320):26, (520,320):27, (620,320):28, (20,420):29, (120,420):30, (220,420):31]
```

They start on `(20, 20)` because I wanted to let some gaps between those rectangles.

The main problem is that no rectangle is printed when I execute this code:

```
public void graph(JFrame frame) {
    buildBackground(frame);
    frame.getGraphics().setColor(Color.WHITE);
    JPanel panel;
    for (DayRectangle d : arraylist) {
        panel = d;
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.repaint();
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is nothing being printed? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be forgetting that a JFrame uses a BorderLayout for its layout manager. Rather you should likely add your Day JPanels into another JPanel that uses GridLayout, and also remember that the Day JPanels will draw relative to their own local coordinate system, and so each Day JPanel should probably draw its rectangle at the same location, starting near 0, 0, not relative to the containing Container.

If you want one JPanel to be a background JPanel, then that should be added to the JFrame in the BorderLayout.CENTER position. Give it a GridLayout, and add your Day JPanels to it, and any JLabels needed (empty if you need empty squares). Also Day may need to be non-opaque if you want background images or colors to show through.

e.g.,

```
public class DayRectangle extends JPanel {
    private static Color RECT_COLOR = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
    private static final int PREF_W = 60;
    private static final int GAP = 4;
    private int posX;
    private int posY;
    private int day;

    public DayRectangle(int posX, int posY, int day) {
        this.posX = posX; // not sure that you need this
        this.posY = posY; // ditto
        this.day = day;

        // if you desire a background to show throw
        // setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(RECT_COLOR);
        g.fillRect(GAP, GAP, PREF_W - 2 * GAP, PREF_W - 2 * GAP);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_W);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("(%d,%d):%d", posX, posY, day);
    }
}
```

For a simple example:

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ExampleGrid extends JPanel {
    public ExampleGrid() {

        JPanel mainGrid = new JPanel();
        mainGrid.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 7));
        // just to show a little off-set of the days
        mainGrid.add(new JLabel());
        mainGrid.add(new JLabel());
        mainGrid.add(new JLabel());

        // now fill the calendar
        for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
            mainGrid.add(new DayRectangle(i + 1));
        }

        JLabel monthLabel = new JLabel("JULY", SwingConstants.CENTER);
        monthLabel.setFont(monthLabel.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 36f));

        // label the days of the week at the top
        String[] daysOfWk = { "Sun", "Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thur", "Fri", "Sat" };
        JPanel daysOfWkPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 7));
        for (String dayOfWk : daysOfWk) {
            daysOfWkPanel.add(new JLabel(dayOfWk, SwingConstants.CENTER));
        }

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        topPanel.add(monthLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        topPanel.add(daysOfWkPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(mainGrid, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        // not sure what you want to do here
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        ExampleGrid mainPanel = new ExampleGrid();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example Grid");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class DayRectangle extends JPanel {
    private static Color RECT_COLOR = Color.LIGHT_GRAY;
    private static final int PREF_W = 60;
    private static final int GAP = 4;
    private static final float FNT_SZ = 20f;
    private int day;

    public DayRectangle(int day) {
        this.day = day;

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        JLabel label = new JLabel("" + day);
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, FNT_SZ));
        add(label);

        // if you desire a background to show throw
        // setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(RECT_COLOR);
        g.fillRect(GAP, GAP, PREF_W - 2 * GAP, PREF_W - 2 * GAP);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_W);
    }

    public int getDay() {
        return day;
    }

}
```

Comment: You're answer was really thankful! With the another answer it was clear that GridLayout was the obvious choice to the problem I had haha However, there are two things that I don't still understand, how can your program know that July (e.g.) starts on Wednesday? In my own program I had that information on the coordinates saved in DayRectangle, but now I don't know how can I set where the grid to start. The other thing is that it seems that some words are missing in your example? At the bottom of the constructor of the Grid and in the constructor of the DayRectangle.
Thanks again ^^

Comment: @hxsh.fx: My program doesn't "know" this as it's only a dumbed-down example program. I've only added a few blank JLabels to show that days can be shifted. You will need to add logic to allow you to know how many JLabels to add (if any) to pad the beginning of the grid.

Comment: And what are the words that are missing on the lanes:
`JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        topPanel.add(monthLabel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        topPanel.add(daysOfWkPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(mainGrid, BorderLayout.CENTER);`
and
`JLabel label = new JLabel("" + day);
        label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(Font.BOLD, FNT_SZ));
        add(label);` ?

Comment: @hxsh.fx: ? not sure what you're asking?

Comment: at the bottom of the constructor of ExampleGrid there are a few lines (setLayout, add, add) that I don't really know what objects are from, topPanel.setLayout? And in the DayRectangle constructor also, the lanes setLayout and add.

Comment: @hxsh.fx: this is standard Swing GUI code with use of nested JPanels and layout managers. Please check out the links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)